# How to create a SELinux policy module with existing output from audit2allow?

Tags: selinux

I know the standard way of creating a SELinux policy module, like

```
cat <auditlog_file> | audit2allow -M <module_name>
```

However, is there a way to create a policy module if all I have is the `why` output from audit2allow, e.g.

```
cat <auditlog_file> | audit2allow
```

Gives me:

```
#============= httpd_t ==============

allow httpd_t default_t:sock_file write;
allow httpd_t unconfined_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

How do I create a policy if I have the above output and not the ability to cat the audit log file again and run it through `audit2allow -M`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the output in `.te` file. In addition you need a few more lines, `module` and `require` [*statements*](https://selinuxproject.org/page/PolicyStatements). You need to define module name and version with `module` statement and required types in `require` statement.

```
module my_module 1.0.0;

require {
    class sock_file { write };
    class unix_stream_socket { connectto };
    type httpd_t, default_t, unconfined_t;
}


allow httpd_t default_t:sock_file write;
allow httpd_t unconfined_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

You can then compile and build the policy module using `checkmodule` and `semodule_package` as described in `audit2allow` man page [examples](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/audit2why.1.html#EXAMPLE):

```
checkmodule -M -m -o my_module.mod my_module.te
semodule_package -o my_module.pp -m my_module.mod
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the detailed explanation and using the sample case that was in my question to provide a thorough solution.